# Elasticsearch index was updated, but document is not in there (ES with php)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch with the official php library and noticed a strange behaviour.

When a new user is registered, I index the document like this:

```
$params = [
    'index' = 'users',
    'id' = 1000,
    'body' => [
        'firstname' => 'Test'
        'lastname' => 'Test',
        'email' => 'test@example.com'
    ]
];

$response = $client->index($params);
```

The $response is this:

```
Array
(
    [_index] => users
    [_type] => _doc
    [_id] => 1000
    [_version] => 1
    [result] => created
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
            [successful] => 1
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [_seq_no] => 21934
    [_primary_term] => 2
)
```

When I load the user list, which uses Elasticsearch of course, the user is not in there.
When I click in the user profil and just save the user without any changes, I use the exact same method like above.

This time $response is this:

```
Array
(
    [_index] => users
    [_type] => _doc
    [_id] => 1000
    [_version] => 2
    [result] => updated
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
            [successful] => 1
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [_seq_no] => 21935
    [_primary_term] => 2
)
```

When I now go back to the user list, the user is there, all good.

So I have two questions:

1. The user should be visible after the first index() call, right?
2. Even if I try to call the index() method a second time during the registration, the user isn't shown in the user list. (The response array is exactly the same as if I save the user profile manually after registration.)

Comment: Have you checked if you use the same index on insert and request within your system? kibana or cerebro can help you getting an overview

Comment: I only have one index yet, so that couldn't be the problem.
But thanks to your tip I installed kibana and finally found the problem. It was a problem in the code, thanks anyways! :)